# Ruby on Rails - Remove Header and Sidebar AdminLTE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to hide header and sidebar AdminLTE, just for signup page? For login, it generates automatically when I run this command `rails g devise:views users`. How about signup page?

[image]

Here is my `routes.rb` :

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users, controller: {
        sessions: "sessions/registrations"
      }
      get 'home/index'
      root :to => 'home#index'
    end
```

and my `application_controller.rb` :

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      before_action :authenticate_user!

      layout 'admin_lte_2'
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you exactly use devise with admin lte but I can see 2 possible solutions

## Option 1

You could define a different route for logged in users:

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end
  get 'user', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

Unauthenticated users will be redirected to **devise/session#new** view (or any other of your choice).

If you would like to have another content shown for those users other than registration page, add unauthenticated root:

```
unauthenticated do
  root 'foo#bar', as: :unauthenticated_root
end
```

## Option 2

Create your custom registration page without header and sidebar. I think it's easier to edit view generated by devise (I don't know if it's good practice tho) than create a custom layout.
You will have probably a view:

```
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
```

just edit it so it will suit your needs.

For creating a custom layout for devise look here:

> [Wiki: Create custom layouts](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Create-custom-layouts)
>
> [Wiki: Customize routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-routes-to-user-registration-pages)

I hope it helps